# Is there a named theorem for the fact that two points define a line, and three points define a quadratic function?

Tags: polynomials

In particular, is there a theorem stating the fact that a polynomial function of degree `d` is defined by `d+1` points?

I'm asking because I want to use this fact in a different proof but I want to be able to cite a theorem for it if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [unisolvence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisolvence_theorem#unisolvence_theorem).